Gauge covariance vs gauge invariance
For Bloch electrons $\psi_{nk}=e^{ikr}u_{nk}$, with $k$ the crystal momentum and $n$ the band index, I would like to know if the integral ($m \neq n, k^\prime \neq k$)
$$
\langle u_{nk}|u_{nk^\prime}\rangle \langle u_{nk^\prime} | u_{mk} \rangle
$$
is gauge covariant or gauge invariant?

What did you even try? Usually you apply some gauge fixing condition and then show that the result doesn't depend on the gauge.

I got an answer from ChatGPT.
Gauge Covariance of Projection Operator Matrix Elements
Consider the Bloch wave functions:
$$
\psi_{n\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}) = e^{i\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}} u_{n\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})
$$
where $ u_{n\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}) $ has the periodicity of the lattice. Under a gauge transformation, the Bloch functions can transform as:
$$
u_{n\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}) \to e^{i\theta_n(\mathbf{k})} u_{n\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})
$$
The projection operator $ |u_{n\mathbf{k}'}\rangle\langle u_{n\mathbf{k}'}| $ acts on a state to project it onto the state $ |u_{n\mathbf{k}'}\rangle $. Under the gauge transformation, this projection operator transforms as follows:
$$
|u_{n\mathbf{k}'}\rangle \to e^{i\theta_n(\mathbf{k}')} |u_{n\mathbf{k}'}\rangle
$$
$$
\langle u_{n\mathbf{k}'}| \to e^{-i\theta_n(\mathbf{k}')} \langle u_{n\mathbf{k}'}|
$$
Thus, the projection operator itself remains unchanged under a gauge transformation:
$$
|u_{n\mathbf{k}'}\rangle\langle u_{n\mathbf{k}'}| \to e^{i\theta_n(\mathbf{k}')} |u_{n\mathbf{k}'}\rangle e^{-i\theta_n(\mathbf{k}')} \langle u_{n\mathbf{k}'}|
$$
$$
= |u_{n\mathbf{k}'}\rangle\langle u_{n\mathbf{k}'}|
$$
Now, consider the matrix elements $ \langle u_{n\mathbf{k}} | |u_{n\mathbf{k}'}\rangle\langle u_{n\mathbf{k}'}| | u_{m\mathbf{k}} \rangle $:
$$
\langle u_{n\mathbf{k}} | |u_{n\mathbf{k}'}\rangle\langle u_{n\mathbf{k}'}| | u_{m\mathbf{k}} \rangle = \langle u_{n\mathbf{k}} |u_{n\mathbf{k}'}\rangle \langle u_{n\mathbf{k}'}| u_{m\mathbf{k}} \rangle
$$
Under a gauge transformation:
$$
u_{n\mathbf{k}} \to e^{i\theta_n(\mathbf{k})} u_{n\mathbf{k}}
$$
$$
u_{m\mathbf{k}} \to e^{i\theta_m(\mathbf{k})} u_{m\mathbf{k}}
$$
$$
u_{n\mathbf{k}'} \to e^{i\theta_n(\mathbf{k}')} u_{n\mathbf{k}'}
$$
The matrix elements transform as:
$$
\langle e^{i\theta_n(\mathbf{k})} u_{n\mathbf{k}} | e^{i\theta_n(\mathbf{k}')} u_{n\mathbf{k}'}\rangle \langle e^{i\theta_n(\mathbf{k}')} u_{n\mathbf{k}'}| e^{i\theta_m(\mathbf{k})} u_{m\mathbf{k}} \rangle
$$
$$
= e^{-i\theta_n(\mathbf{k})} \langle u_{n\mathbf{k}} | e^{i\theta_n(\mathbf{k}')} u_{n\mathbf{k}'}\rangle e^{-i\theta_n(\mathbf{k}')} \langle u_{n\mathbf{k}'}| e^{i\theta_m(\mathbf{k})} u_{m\mathbf{k}} \rangle
$$
$$
= e^{-i\theta_n(\mathbf{k})} e^{i\theta_n(\mathbf{k}')} \langle u_{n\mathbf{k}} | u_{n\mathbf{k}'}\rangle e^{-i\theta_n(\mathbf{k}')} e^{i\theta_m(\mathbf{k})} \langle u_{n\mathbf{k}'}| u_{m\mathbf{k}} \rangle
$$
$$
= e^{-i(\theta_n(\mathbf{k}) - \theta_n(\mathbf{k}'))} e^{i(\theta_m(\mathbf{k}) - \theta_n(\mathbf{k}'))} \langle u_{n\mathbf{k}} | u_{n\mathbf{k}'}\rangle \langle u_{n\mathbf{k}'}| u_{m\mathbf{k}} \rangle
$$
$$
= e^{i(\theta_m(\mathbf{k}) - \theta_n(\mathbf{k}))} \langle u_{n\mathbf{k}} | u_{n\mathbf{k}'}\rangle \langle u_{n\mathbf{k}'}| u_{m\mathbf{k}} \rangle
$$
This shows that the matrix elements are gauge covariant, as they transform by a phase factor under the gauge transformation.
